# Evolving an interface that is not supposed to be implemented by the client

Tags: java, design, api, interfaces

I'm about to write a Java library. Basically, this library provides something like this to its user:

```
interface Foo {
  void doA();
  boolean aWorked();
  void doB(int value);
}
```

The user is **not supposed to implement** this interface (obviously). Thus, user code will look something like this:

```
Foo f = Library::SomeFactory();
if (someDecison()) {
  f.doA();
  if (!f.aWorked()) {
    f.doB(21);
  }
} else {
  f.doB(42);
}
```

I can make sure that **neither preconditions nor postconditions of the methods in the interface change** in the future. But there might be a new method, say `doC()`.

Now, various resources including [Orcale's Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/nogrow.html) suggest that just adding this `doC()` to above interface is a bad idea. They propose different solutions from extending the interface ...

```
interface Foo2 : extends Foo {
  void doC();
}
```

... to blowing the code up with command patterns and what not. But the supporting reason is always that "all implementing classes must be changed". That's not an issue in my case, as all implementing classes are "under my control" and *will need to be changed either way* (when there's a `doC()`).

**Is simply adding the method to `Foo` really a bad idea? And if so, why?** Is there anything that I'm not taking into account here? My primary goal is to not break any user code written against that interface.

```
// That's what I'm planning
interface Foo {
  void doA();
  boolean aWorked();
  void doB(int value);
  void doC();
}
```

---

[This source](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Evolving_Java-based_APIs) supports my feeling that it can be as simple as that:

> [..] If the method is added to a class (interface) which Clients are not allowed to subclass (to implement), then it is not a breaking change. [..]

Comment: If all the classes implementing the interface (that you know about) are under your control, and you know that you are going to have to go through and update them all, what is the issue with following the suggestion in Oracle Docs?  That is, if you create a Foo2 interface that extends Foo, updating the appropriate classes to implement Foo2 should not be a big deal, no?

Comment: @MatthewFlynn indeed, but I fear that the external interface of the API then gets possibly confusing to the users. I need to say that these users are all going to be relatively inexperienced students. I'm currently considering putting the interfaces in "versioned packages", e.g `foo1.Foo`, `foo2.Foo`, .. perhaps I'm also over thinking this.

Comment: Will that always be how the client executes the code? Will there be code in-between `f.doA(); if(f.aWorked()) f.doB(21);`? Or will those statements always execute one right after the other?

Comment: Why not just add a warning in the JavaDoc: "This interface is provided solely for communication with this API. The author reserves the right to extend the interface at any time, so your code will break if you implement this interface."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Java mechanism to prevent clients from implementing an interface that is accessible to them.  The text you're quoting says "is not allowed to implement".  Sadly, the only way that can be true (enforced) is if the interface is inaccessible to the client.

There are reasons a client may want to implement that interface; for example, if they are trying to bring together several different libraries, and they find your interface to be a good abstraction to reuse.

You can caution your clients against implementing your interface -- that your intention is to extend it, or, you can use Java's new default methods when you do extend the interface (or both).

Comment: At first I wanted to comment that there's no rational reason (or gain) for a client to implement the interface on its own, but then I thought about testing/mocking, implementing some form of logging, network bridging, other uses for the decorator design pattern, ... So I guess there are indeed valid reasons for the client to implement this interface on its own.

Answer (score 3):

Best practices are fine and dandy, but it's important to be pragmatic.

In this case, I see nothing wrong with extending your interface in-place in the future.  Like you mentioned, the only affected classes are in your control.

Also, why have a `aWorked()` member if you can simply have `doA()` return a success/failure result?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's what I was hoping for. Oh: That `aWorked` is just an example for a "query" method. Indeed, if this were real code then `doA` should just return a `bool` :)

Comment: @DanielJour That's the problem with foobar examples. People take them literally. It would be nicer to give a little more domain context (even invented for the answer but similar to the real problem) instead of the trite foobar examples.

Answer (score 1):

## Evolving an interface without breaking code

Any new methods should supply [default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) behavior, which is an easier (and cleaner) alternative to defining a new subtype.

## Why is adding a new abstract method to an interface bad?

It does exactly what you want avoid: break code. If clients used a newer version of your framework for bug fixes, they'll be forced to declare the new method in whatever types implement the interface.

## Preventing clients from implementing your interface

Even if Java supported this, which it doesn't, I would advise against it. You would limiting the usage your framework.

If your framework lacks an implementation the client may require/want, they (or anyone else, maybe a more experienced developer) should be able to extend upon `Foo` to expose new useful implementations that you may not have had the time to write, or maybe never even thought of.

Comment: -1 for the "_Any new methods should supply default behavior_" suggestion. You are trading compilation errors for some arbitrary behavior when some code calls `doC` on a class that did not implement `doC` even though it needed to because the compiler did not point you to it because `doC` had a default implementation, and you forgot about that class' existence so at no point did a programmer looked at that class and made a choice whether or not it needs to have it's own implementation for `doC`.

Comment: @IdanArye How is the behavior arbitrary/random if there's a contract? If you wanted/needed to extend the contract for implementation specific behavior, you could override the method. Yeah, there's no error forcing your to declare the method, but that's because an implementation (that abides by the contract defined in the parent type) already exists. The only reason a dev would not implement `doC()` is if they didn't need to extend the contract, or if they didn't understand how the parent type works (didn't read contract). `default` removes the need to modify code if not needed (bug fix update)

Comment: There is another reason for a dev to not implement `doC` - if `doC` did not exist when they implemented the class. Using the metaphor, this is similar to adding new clauses to a signed contract without notifying the other party. Even if you are legally allowed to, you can't realistically expect them to respect these new clauses. Sometimes you don't need them to(e.g. the methods on streams), but if you insist on providing a default implementation for **any** new method you'll have to add stub implementations for the cases that are not sugar for utility methods - and this rarely works well...

Comment: @IdanArye Clients aren't forced to use the method. This is primarily for backwards binary compatibility. Otherwise, anyone using the framework would either: 1. Be forced to cange all current uses of `Foo` to `Foo2` to use the new functionality (scale up) 2. Be forced to modify their code just to make sure it compiles, even if they don't care to scale up by using the new functionality. Maybe they just want the optimizations and bug fixes that are bundled with the framework updates.

Comment: @IdanArye It definitely works. I'm sure you've used [`Collection#stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) before. Without defaults, youd be forced to use a different type (`List2`) to use `stream()`. If you wanted to implement `stream()` in your code, you'd have to change `List` to `List2`, rather than just calling it directly from the existing `List`. As more revisions are made, you end up with `List5`, [if not worse](http://help.solidworks.com/2016/English/api/SWHelp_List.html?id=19075c7f484247b8a20ec4b34cbbf917#Pg0&ProductType=&ProductName=).

Comment: `Stream` is exactly the example I've given for "Sometimes you don't need them to" - but there are cases where it doesn't work. Let's say you have an interface for interacting with a file hosting service, that has methods for listing, writing, and reading files. The client implemented this interface for DropBox, Box.net and GoogleDrive, and is passing these classes to a GUI class you have provided that allows interacting with the service via GUI. (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) Now, let's say you also want to support deleting files. So you add a delete method to the interface, and because you have a rule that you **must always** provide a default implementation for new methods you want to provide a default implementation, but you can't - because this requires knowledge of the specific web service's API. So you do the closest thing - you provide a default implementation that writes an empty file, deleting the data but not the entry. (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) You also add a delete button to the GUI, and to avoid redundant web requests you decide that instead of asking again for the list of files after a delete, you simply remove the entry from the list in the GUI. Now, your client has upgraded your software and hurray - it compiles without them having to change a thing! Their QA opens the new version and tries to delete a file on DropBox, and the file is indeed removed from the list. Hurray, everything works! (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) Well, a decent QA will find the bug eventually, and may even notice it happens with all supported hosting services - but is it really OK to convert a compilation error to a bug that will be discovered so far down the QA?

Comment: Adding `delete` and *requiring* users to specify an implementation is a totally different situation, which you *must* break code to do. It means the semantics of the framework had changed: before, you didn't need to delete, and software depending on your framework worked without the delete feature. Now you want users to define `delete`, even though previous versions were used without it. If devs like how the software was initially, and don't want to scale up and make use of the delete function, you shouldn't force them to. It could still be there, just not utilized for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47990/discussion-between-vince-emigh-and-idan-arye).

Answer (score 0):

If the interface is not supposed to be implemented by the client, you should make it package-private so clients will not even know it exists.  If it defines a type that is part of your public API, you could make it a superclass of your own implementations.  The superclass could be `abstract` or have a package-private constructor, and the implementations could be closed to extension by declaring them `final` or restricting access to their constructors.

You can always remove these restrictions later if you discover a compelling reason to do so.  But you can't add them later without risking breakage in third-party code.  So it's good practice in a public API to limit the visibility and extensibility of everything as much as possible, and open it up later.

Comment: If `Foo` was package-private, users wouldn't be able to call methods from it. `f.doA()` would cause a compiler error.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I missed that the OP's code sample represents user code.